# Lifting a module up the package hierarchy in python 3.11

Tags: import, module, package, python-3.11

I have this file structure

```
.
├── mt_pipe
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── src
│       └── commands.py
└── test.ipynb
```

The content of commands.py is

```
def greet():
    print("Hi")
```

In the jupyternotebook, I can import greet by

`from mt_pipe.src.commands import greet`

But I want to import it as

`from mt_pipe.commands import greet`

So I added the line `from .src import commands` to the `__init__.py` file. But it gives the error `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mt_pipe.commands'"`

ChatGPT and Bard says to add the line
`from .src.commands import *`
to the init file which makes no sense and gives no success.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Successfully import with
`from mt_pipe.commands import greet`